# How to set caml query for special view?

Tags: 2010, web-part, spquery

I have a list with 3 views.

I want find special items of this. I use SPQuery for it.

```
<Where>
 <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name='TypeTitle' />
   <Value Type='Lookup'>Test1</Value>
 </Eq>
</Where>
```

and getitems of list :

```
string viewname="View1";
list.GetItems(query,viewname).GetDataTable();
```

But return all items of view allitems with name :Test1. While the there is no item to View1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the definition of the `SPList.GetItems(SPQuery,string)` method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434064.aspx

You can see that the second parameter needs to be the GUID of the view enclosed in curly braces. Eg: `{B080E5D2-DEF9-11E1-8A8D-550A6188709B}`

Try the following code:

```
string viewGUID = list.Views["View1"].ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
list.GetItems(query,viewGUID).GetDataTable();
```

Also, in the MSDN docs it is stated that:

> The properties of the view that is specified by the viewName parameter
>   override the properties that are specified in the query object that is
>   passed through the query parameter. For example, if the query object
>   includes a  tag that specifies only items containing a
>   particular column value, while the view specifies to return all items,
>   this method retrieves all of the items